# MVC Entity collections that is sorted

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following entity

```
public class Meeting
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    private ICollection<MeetingPeriod> _meetingTimes;
    public virtual ICollection<MeetingPeriod> MeetingTimes
    {
        get { return _meetingTimes ?? (_meetingTimes = new Collection<MeetingPeriod>()); }
        protected set { _meetingTimes = value; }
    }
}
```

Got a few questions:

When I get a record I would like all the MeetingTimes to be sorted by default. Is this possible? I tried to return _meetingTimes.OrderBy but then I could not add any more meeting times as it was a readonly list.

I have added override Equals() to MeetingPeriod object. However when I try to compare MeetingTimes to an array of MeetingPeriod seems like the Equal() isn't getting called. What is going on here? It does get called correctly elsewhere. Seems like something to do with ICollection?

Comment: You can sort the collection while creating database call using LINQ

Comment: Got a few questions: 
    What you mean you couldn't add any more meeting times as it was a readonly list?
    What you mean _"seems like the Equal() isn't getting called"_?

Comment: Order them on consumption, not within the entity. Where you would normally iterate over MeetingTimes with a foreach for example, foreach(var meetingTime in meeting.MeetingTimes.OrderBy(x=> x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)) { }

Typically if you are returning data to a view for example (MVC/MVVM) I suggest not passing back Entities, but rather a POCO view model with just the details about the entity and relationships that you need. With that if you include meeting times you can order them when populating the meeting time view model collection. From there order can be adjusted client-side.